# Read from QAudioInput

Tags: qt, qaudioinput

I struggle reading data from a QAudioInput. What I'd like to do is read data from the buffer in chunks and then perform some processing on it. I don't want to write the data stream to a file as in most examples.

What I tried is this:

```
    audioInput = new QAudioInput(info);
    audioInput->setBufferSize(buffer_size);
    audioInput->setNotifyInterval(250);

    qDebug() << "Error = " << audioInput->error();

    audioIODevice = audioInput->start();
    qDebug() << "dev=" << audioIODevice;
```

It seems that I can create the QAudioInput object. However, when I start it I get a null pointer back as QIODevice. Based on the documentation...

```
QIODevice *QAudioInput::start()

Returns a pointer to the internal QIODevice being used to transfer data from the system's audio input. The device will already be open and read() can read data directly from it.
```

... I'd have expected to get back a valid handle.

The device I try to read from is reported as "alsa_input.usb-Logitech_Logitech_USB_Headset-00.mono-fallback", in case this matters.

Comment: Are you getting an error? Did you check for errors before and after the start() method? Is the state changing?

Comment: I don't get an error (I print if in the qDebug() statement before)